# Need help regarding one LALR(1) parsing

Tags: javascript, lalr, compiler-compiler

I am trying to parse a context-free language, called [Context Free Art](http://www.contextfreeart.org). I have created its parser in Javascript using a YACC-like JS LALR(1) parser generator [JSCC](http://jscc.jmksf.com/).

Take the example of following CFA (Context Free Art) code. This code is a valid CFA.

```
startshape A
rule A { CIRCLE { s 1} }
```

Notice the `A` and `s` in above. `s` is a command to scale the `CIRCLE`, but `A` is just a name of this rule. In the language's grammar I have set `s` as token `SCALE` and `A` comes under token `STRING` (I have a regular expression to match string and it is at the bottom of of all tokens).

This works fine, but in the below case it breaks.

```
startshape s
rule s { CIRCLE { s 1} }
```

This too is a perfectly valid code, but since my parser marks `s` after `rule` as `SCALE` token so it errors out saying that it was expecting `STRING`.

Now my question is, if there is any way to re-write the production rules of the parser to account for this? The related production rule is:-

```
rule:
    RULE STRING '{' buncha_replacements '}'    [* rule(%2, 1) *]
    |
    RULE STRING RATIONAL '{' buncha_replacements '}'  [* rule(%2, 1*%3) *]
    ;
```

One simple solution I can think of is create a copy of above rule with `STRING` replaced by `SCALE`, but this is just one of the many similar rules which would need such fixing. Furthermore there are many other terminals which can get matched to `STRING`. So that means way too many rules!

Comment: Just an add-on to above. YACC (or maybe Bison) supports type tokens. So for them if we declare `STRING` as a type token then `s` can be both `SCALE` and `STRING`, solving this problem. Not sure if this can be done in JSCC.

Answer (score 0):

Yes! Finally the solution to my problem has hit me. All I need to do is modify my above production to:-

```
rule:
    RULE user_string '{' buncha_replacements '}'    [* rule(%2, 1) *]
    |
    RULE user_string RATIONAL '{' buncha_replacements '}'  [* rule(%2, 1*%3) *]
    ;

user_string:
    STRING | SCALE ;
```

This is a pretty elegant solution compared to what I mentioned in my problem text. If anybody has any better solution then please do comment.